# Удалить сохранённые данные

Tags: html, google-chrome

Я добавил к формам ввода `autocomplete="off"`, но сохранённые данные(логин и пароль) все равно отображаются в этих формах. Как устранить данную проблему?

Comment: Очистить сохранённые браузером данные. Новые пароли не должны уже сохраняться, а вы видите старые.

Comment: Вы меня не правильно поняли. Сохраненные данные отображаются на страницах, где есть формы ввода к которым привязано сохранение. То что на странице входа они отображаются - это хорошо, но они отображаются ещё и на странице регистрации потому как формы ввода идентичны, что на странице входа, что на странице регистрации. Ранее это решалось добавляя к форму ввода autocomplete="off", но сейчас это не работает.